# A compact subspace

Tags: general-topology

$(0,1]$ is said to be closed in it's subspace topology, but not sequentially compact. Is that because it isn't bounded below? A sequence doesn't converge but the subspace is closed so I was confused.

Comment: Every set is closed in its own topology, since the empty set is always open. The sequence $\{\frac1n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence (any value $\epsilon\in(0,1]$ must be above $\frac1m$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$, so for $k>2m$, $\frac1k\notin B(\epsilon,\frac1{2m})$.)

Comment: @donthousand Don thousand Don thousand I am hearing that we should ignore the subspace's topology with respect to compactness. However this answer was otherwise very useful thank you very much-

Answer (score 1):

Heine-Borel theorem states every closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. The important part of this theorem is that the subset given in the statement must be closed under the usual topology over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$(0,1]$ itself is closed subset under the natural subspace topology. However, it is **not** a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, Heine-Borel cannot be applied.

---

Moreover, Heine-Borel theorem is a theorem for metric spaces called $\mathbb{R}^n$, and its statement involves with a non-topological property - namely boundedness. 
Hence there is no reason to apply Heine-Borel theorem to $(0,1]$: we do not know $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(0,1]$ is *isometric* (i.e. both of them have the same metric structure.)

By the same reason, we cannot apply this theorem for $(0,1)$, although it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. they are essentially the same topological space).

Comment: How come it defined closed bounded sets as compact, that is the same as the definition of compactness @Hanuljeon.

Comment: @7einadh Some textbooks (especially, books about elementary analysis) may adopt the definition of compact as "closed and bounded"; this is not a universal definition. It cannot be applied to every topological space, and even more, every metric space.

Comment: That is, we can find an example of closed bounded subset of a given metric space which is not sequentially compact; for example, consider the metric over $\mathbb{R}$ given by $d(x,y)=\max(|x-y|,1)$. We can see that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded under $d$, but not every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is sequentially compact.

Answer (score 0):

$(0,1]$ is bounded from below ! Suppose that $(0,1]$ is  sequentially compact in the subspace topoology. Then the sequence $(1/n)$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in  $(0,1]$. But this limit $=0$ and $0 \notin (0,1]$  . Contradiction.

Comment: I've read the advice and I think I am getting it now. $(0,1]$ is bounded from below as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It's not bounded from below in the subspace topology of $(0,1]$. Right!?

Comment: No. Boundedness has nothing to do with topology. We have $0 <x$ for all $x \in (0,1].$

Comment: Maybe that is what I ought to do with my other question, disregard the subspace topology on the "topologist''s sine curve" in order to look at if any sequences are closed am I right? Thanks @Fred ^_^